# How to add values to pass to a TouchableOpacity on press - React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

In web React I can do something like this:

```
const handleClick = ({ target: { dataset } }) => 
{
    const buttonValue = dataset.somevalue;
}

return (
  <div>
    <button data-somevalue="value1" onClick={handleClick}>
        ButtonText
    </button>

    <button data-somevalue="value2" onClick={handleClick}>
        ButtonText
    </button>
  </div>
)
```

or it can even done with other attributes like `name`.

I have tried this:

```
const handlePress = (value) =>
{
    console.log(value);
}

return (
    <Viev>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePress("value1")}>
          <Text>ButtonText</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePress("value2")}>
          <Text>ButtonText</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </Viev>
)
```

But dosen't work as expected, so how can I achieve this?

Comment: below both are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple you need to pass the arrow function,Below I shared the updated code.you can try and let me know further.

```
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>handlePress("value1")}>
          <Text>ButtonText</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>handlePress("value2")}>
          <Text>ButtonText</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the following format.

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
    handlePress('value1');
  }}>
  <Text>ButtonText</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
    handlePress('value2');
  }}>
  <Text>ButtonText</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```